# Java Sizing JPanel & JPanel Components

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to build a GUI in Java Swing. I have alot of trouble sizing components. I managed to size a JPanel by setting the dimensions with `setPreferredSize()`, but I can't get the components within that JPanel to size properly.

This is my screen with only the JPanel visible.

[image]

When I add the button to my JPanel the following happens:

[image]

As you can see the button is taking up the whole lenght and width of my JPanel/JFrame. Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

Here is my code:

**Application.java**

```
public void start() {
    ControllerObserveer observeer = new ControllerObserveer();

    frame = new JFrame("-");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.add(observeer.getView(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setResizable(false);
}
```

**ControllerObserveer.java**

```
public class ControllerObserveer {
    private ModelObserveer model;
    private ViewObserveer view; 

    public JPanel getView(){
        return this.view.p;
    }
}
```

**ViewObserveer.java**

```
public class ViewObserveer {

    public JPanel p;

    public ViewObserveer(){
        this.p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(), false);
        p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        p.setBackground(Color.red);

        JButton b = new JButton("Hello World!");
        b.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 40));

        p.add(b);

    }
}
```

At last I would like to ask what the diffrences are between the diffrent layouts, like `BorderLayout()` or `BoxLayout()` for example.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: You are using `BorderLayout`. This is the default behavior of `BorderLayout` in which the component added to center will fill the whole panel if there were no component added to other parts of the container such as WEST, EAST, NORTH, SOUTH. You may want to consider learning about LayoutManagers in java first.

Comment: *"At last I would like to ask what the diffrences are between the diffrent layouts, "* Do the [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) lesson of the tutorial. This is stuff you need to know in order to create Swing GUIs, and it is far too much to be covered in a Q&A site like SO. Voting to class as 'too broad'.

Comment: `I managed to size a JPanel by setting the dimensions with setPreferredSize(),` - don't use setPreferredSize(). Every Swing component will determine its own size. A JPanel will determine is size based on the components added to the panel and the layout manager that is being used.

Answer (score 0):

Install Java WindowBuilder on Eclipse. So, you can get things done.. "but I can't get the components within that JPanel to size properly."

[image]

Comment: Don't use an IDE to generate the code. You don't learn anything about Swing and the code is not maintainable and portable if you move to a different IDE. Learn how to use Layout Managers effectively.

Comment: at least you get the size.